# How do you prevent the WebClient class from automatically following the location in headers?

Tags: c#, .net, header, location, webclient

Is it possible on the WebClient class?

E.g. something like:

```
MyWebClient.AllowAutoRedirect = false; (of HttpWebRequest)
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You could write a custom web client and *enable* this functionality:

```
public class WebClientEx : WebClient
{
    protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        return request;
    }
}
```

and then:

```
using (var client = new WebClientEx())
{
    Console.WriteLine(client.DownloadString("http://google.com"));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing, customized client is an excellent idea.