# WebClient or WebRequest to get the re-directed URL of the landing page

Tags: vb.net, winforms, proxy, webclient, webrequest

From the string I parsed from [Bing's Pic of the Day](http://www.bing.com/HPImageArchive.aspx?format=xml&idx=0&n=1&mkt=en-US), I got the info of the pic to be downloaded, let's say today it is `/az/hprichbg/rb/PearlHarborWindows_EN-US8565186567`, then we will have full URL of the image be like `http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/PearlHarborWindows_EN-US8565186567_1366x768.jpg`

Usually Bing has an image of higher resolutions, so I will download the image 1920x1200 too. It's easy with the URL changed to be like `http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/PearlHarborWindows_EN-US8565186567_1920x1200.jpg`, then give the task to a `WebClient` such as `client1.DownloadFile(url, fileName)`

The issue here is, some days, the resolution 1920x1200 is not available, and the download URL of this res.(1920x1200) will be re-directed to the URL of the image **`/sa/simg/hpb/NorthMale_EN-US8782628354_1920x1200.jpg`** - as default (you can check it).

So my try was a function to get the return/re-directed URL from the input URL:

```
 Public Function GetWebPageURL(ByVal url As String) As String
    Dim Request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create(url)
    Request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
    Return Request.RequestUri.ToString 
 End Function
```

and compare to the input URL to see it they are different, but the result was not as expected.

Could anyone let me know the method to check this re-directed URL, like the return URL after we press Enter and wait for the site to load.

Please give me idea to overcome this obstacle. Thank you!

**Notes:** *Some issues related to access rights on different PCs cause me not to use `HttpWebRequest`, so I prefer the solution not using `HttpWebRequest` (`WebClient` or others are better).*

---

With help from @IvanValadares @AlenGenzić, and suggestion of `Proxy` for `HttpWebRequest` from @Jimi, I have come to the fair solution, as the below code:

```
    url1 = "http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/PearlHarborWindows_EN-US8565186567_1920x1200.jpg"

    Dim myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url1), HttpWebRequest)
    myHttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1
    myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    Dim defaultProxy As IWebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
    If (defaultProxy IsNot Nothing) Then
        defaultProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = defaultProxy
    End If

    Dim myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
    url2 = myHttpWebResponse.ResponseUri.ToString

    Label1.Text = url1
    Label2.Text = url2
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Download file through code that has a redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11749676/download-file-through-code-that-has-a-redirect)

Comment: Thanks @AlenGenzić, you're so fast on searching the similar issue! But I prefer the `WebClient` to `HttpWebRequest`, because I encountered some issue related to access right on some PCs.

Comment: In the background, WebClient uses HttpWebRequest anyway, so it is interesting that it works in the first place.

Comment: What has to do `WebRequest` with *access rights*? The file you download is yours to manage. `WebRequest` has nothing related to files. If you prefer to use WebClient (which uses WebRequest, as already noted), because you know how to use it, create a control derived from it. [One of the many related questions on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726889/how-do-you-prevent-the-webclient-class-from-automatically-following-the-location).

Comment: I got the System.Net.WebException on the line
`Dim myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)` @Jimi @AlenGenzić

Comment: If the below error occurs, what solution should we switch to?
`System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.`

Comment: Well, apparently there's a Proxy in between your machine and the remote machine. You need credentials to authenticate your request, otherwise the Proxy will block it. Search SO for "HttpWebRequest"  (or WebClient of HttpClient) and "Proxy".

Comment: With @Jimi advice, I navigated to [How can I get WebClient (webservice client) to automatically use the default proxy server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16966486/how-can-i-get-webclient-webservice-client-to-automatically-use-the-default-pro)
With the credentials and proxy settings, the WebException is no longer thrown. Thank you all for your kind helps!

Comment: @nambk  I'm glad to hear you solved it. Good job :) You could post it as an answer to your own question.

Comment: Hi @Jimi, could you post another reply so I can mark this question as answered? Thank you.

Comment: I didn't solve the problem. You actually did. Post your answer to the question and then mark it as answered yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With help from @IvanValadares @AlenGenzić, and suggestion of `Proxy` for `HttpWebRequest` from @Jimi, I have come to the fair solution as below:

```
    url1 = "http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/PearlHarborWindows_EN-US8565186567_1920x1200.jpg"

    Dim myHttpWebRequest As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(url1), HttpWebRequest)
    myHttpWebRequest.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 1
    myHttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True
    Dim defaultProxy As IWebProxy = WebRequest.DefaultWebProxy
    If (defaultProxy IsNot Nothing) Then
        defaultProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = defaultProxy
    End If

    Dim myHttpWebResponse As HttpWebResponse = CType(myHttpWebRequest.GetResponse, HttpWebResponse)
    url2 = myHttpWebResponse.ResponseUri.ToString

    Label1.Text = url1
    Label2.Text = url2
```

The `System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.` is no longer thrown.

Comment: As a note, your `WebRequest` authetication might be rejected by the Proxy if your resource requires an `Https` connection. You could resolve changing `https` to `http`. Most of the services automatically change the protocol to `https` when needed (you might get a redirection here, so also keep `AllowAutoRedirect = true`). Some services don't.

Answer (score 1):

Use AllowAutoRedirect and check the StatusCode.

```
var webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/PearlHarborWindows_EN-US8565186567_1920x1200.jpg");
    webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())
    {
       if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
       {
          // Have been redirect
       }
       else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
       {
          // Have not been redirect
       }
    }
```

Using HttpClient

```
 var handler = new HttpClientHandler()
 {
    AllowAutoRedirect = false
 };
 HttpClient client = new HttpClient(handler);
 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync("http://www.bing.com/az/hprichbg/rb/PearlHarborWindows_EN-US8565186567_1920x1200.jpg");
 if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Found)
 {
     // Have been redirect
 }
 else if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
 {
     // Have not been redirect
 }
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan! Some issues related to access right on different PCs cause me not to use `HttpWebRequest`, could you advice me other ideas on this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can also use AllowAutoRedirect  with HttpClient

Comment: I got the System.Net.WebException on the line `using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse())`

Comment: If the below error occurs, what solution should we switch to?
`System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (407) Proxy Authentication Required.`

Comment: Do you need to use a proxy? Because your code is : "myHttpWebRequest.Proxy = defaultProxy" , are the credentials correct to that proxy?

Comment: I guess so, because the code run well with no web exception. It seems it uses the default proxy with the same credentials when using the default web browser.